# FireBase Store /Storage Which one of this it is a correct approach?

Tags: firebase

I'm starting to learn little by little, about this services and NoSQL world but I still have some doubts.

I am creating an android app where the users can upload tagged images, and then the rest of the users can visualize by watching the corresponding tag.

So when a Users upload an images (it is storaged in "Storage" Right?)

What is the correct way to procced?

A) Create a folder in the storage, with the username "UsernameImages" and then attach the path link to the user, so when he wants to watch his own pictures, only need of that link

B) Put all the images on a same path "Images", and then give the url to each of the image uploaded by the user to his own collection in FireBase Store?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Rod, there are several ways to approach this. I think you could use Firestore and Storage work together in this task. You could store in a Firestore collection all your *TagImages*. Documents in this collection would have all the data about images: downloadURL (comes from Storage), an Array of tags (wich you'll use to make queries), a unix representing the creation, data about the user who created it and so on. Then in storage you could create paths like /tagImages/${uid}/tagname/fileName. This way you then can control write and read with Firebase Rules.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero That really sounds like an answer ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @LucasDavidFerrero